# C# суммировать отрицательныe числа

Tags: c#

```
int[] numbers = {5, -6, 2, 7, -5, 9, 1, -3};
int summ = 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= numbers.Length; i++) {
    if (i < 0) {
        summ += numbers[i];
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(summ);
Console.ReadKey();
```

ответ дает 1 не понимаю что делать

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40808/discussion-on-question-by-zeroone-c--e-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

И я хочу ответ написать))

```
int summ=0;
foreach(int r in new int[]{  5, -6, 2, 7, -5, 9, 1, -3 } ) summ+=(r<0)?r:0;
```

Comment: сложний уровен язика да? проста я ничего не понял но главное все работает, спасибо

Comment: @Zeroone массив обвёрнут в foreach, можно было foreach (int r in numbers) summ +=/*сумма*/ (r<0 /*условие*/)?r /*если да*/:0 /*если нет*/;

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение

Comment: @nick_n_a   © я бы не отвечал на вопросы-задания, похожие на лабки. Пожайлуста, не превращайте форум в мусорку.

Answer (score 7):

Здесь не обойтись без Linq.
[Функция `Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx), чтобы выбрать отрицательные
[Функция `Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338442(v=vs.110).aspx), для получения суммы

```
int[] numbers = { 5, -6, 2, 7, -5, 9, 1, -3 };
var r = numbers.Where(el=>el<0).Sum();
```

Так же можно воспользоваться [перегрузкой `Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb535184(v=vs.110).aspx) и обойтись без `Where`

```
int[] numbers = { 5, -6, 2, 7, -5, 9, 1, -3 };
var r = numbers.Sum(el=>el<0?el:0);
```

Comment: ну это вы загнули) Без LINQ всегда можно обойтись)

Comment: Препод сьест студента за такой ответ)))))

Comment: Ну какой Linq? Человек не может внятно цикл `for` написать, так давайте ткнем его в Linq.

Comment: @Igor, ну а зачем ему `for` если все уже придумано до нас? :-)

Comment: @nick_n_a так и задумано.

Comment: @Igor, как ни страно, но Linq значительно проще для понимания, чем циклы (ИМХО)

Comment: спасибо болщое но мне нужно без linq как та это реализовать

Comment: @Grundy, а если у них в универе стоят XP с VS2005 и .Net не выше 3.0?

Comment: @AlexKrass, значит у них плохой универ :)

Comment: @Grundy компи у нас на винд 10 но вот препод из 70_тих :/

Comment: @Grundy, ну ладно, тут я утрирую. Но вот факт, что WinXP не поддерживает .Net 4.5, как-то раз опечалил. Хорошо хоть переписывать ничего не пришлось.

Comment: (new List<int>(numbers)).ForEach(t => summ += (t < 0) ? t : 0); Как обойтись без Linq))))

Comment: @nick_n_a, нет объявления _summ_ :P

Comment: Тогда так int summ=0; (new List<int>(numbers)).ForEach(t => summ += (t < 0) ? t : 0);

Comment: @nick_n_a, ага, вот теперь похоже на правду :)

Answer (score 5):

```
int summ = 0; //здесь была первая ошибка
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) //здесь была третья ошибка найденная Igor
{
    if (numbers[i]<0) //здесь была вторая ошибка
    {
        summ += numbers[i];
    }              
}
```

Comment: `i <= numbers.Length`  error #3

Comment: @Igor, да вы правы, я просмотрел третью, но уже исправил

Comment: думаю так правильно спасибо за ответ, но сейчас ловит ексепшен indexoutofrangeexception наверное это другой вопрос уже

Comment: @Zeroone, там была еще третья ошибка в сравнении -- уберите символ '='

Comment: @Mirdin спасибо,заработала

Answer (score -1):

```
sum = numbers.Where(w=>w < 0).Sum();
```

Еще проще :)

Comment: Ответ третий по списку такой же самый как этот

Comment: @nick_n_a, у меня параметр в лямбде `el` а тут `w` :-)

Comment: Тооочно сорян, я как-то смотрю все циклы предлагают, тернарные операции. Linq же проще

Comment: Минус за дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/530006/182771